# OpenAPI Python Generator - convert from dict to model

Tags: python, openapi-generator

Using openapi generator for python, I get a bunch of generated models, which I can instantiate like so:

```py
> yoda = Jedi(name="Yoda", light_saber=LightSaber(colour="green"))
```

I can convert these to a dict nice and easily using the `.to_dict()` method:

```py
> yoda.to_dict()
{"name": "Yoda", "light_saber": {"colour": "green"}}
```

However I'm not sure how I can deserialise from a dict back to the appropriate model.

I've tried the following and get a type error:

```py
> Jedi(**yoda_dict)
...
my_client.exceptions.ApiTypeError: Invalid type for variable 'light_saber'.
Required value type is LightSaber and passed type was dict at ['light_saber']
```

I also get the same error with `Jedi._from_openapi_data(**yoda_dict)`

Is there a way to convert from a dict to a typed openapi generated model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out openapi only tries to convert types if you pass in the `_configuration` property. I was able to deserialise successfully with

```py
from my_client.configuration import Configuration

Jedi(**yoda_dict, _configuration=Configuration())
```

Note that I also hit [this bug](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11299) as I'm using `allOf` in my schemas. So also had to downgrade to openapi generator 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-serialize the lightsaber first in your dictionary, then you can pass it back to `Jedi`:

```py
yoda_dict['light_saber'] = LightSaber(**yoda_dict['light_saber'])

Jedi(**yoda_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know if there's any way to do this without having to manually deserialise inner objects? Otherwise if the internals of the `Jedi` model changes I'll need to continually update the code that deserialises it :)